# JAVAX: unwanted attribute

Tags: java, xml, soap, javax

While adding a new node into SOAPElement I'm getting an extra, unwanted attribute xmlns="".
How can I solve it?

```
...
SOAPFactory factory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
SOAPElement securityElem = factory.createElement("Security", null, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
SOAPElement tokenElem = factory.createElement("UsernameToken");
...
securityElem.addChildElement(tokenElem);
```

Result:

```
<Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <UsernameToken xmlns=""/> </Security>
```

But I need this:

```
<Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
             <UsernameToken/> </Security>
```

Comment: RESULT: <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <UsernameToken xmlns=""/>
</Security>

Comment: NEED: <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <UsernameToken/>
</Security>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the element to be in the same namespace as its parent element, you must explicitly create it in that namespace by supplying the URI to the createElement() call. If you create a no-namespace element (as you have done), then the serializer inserts a namespace undeclaration `xmlns=""` to indicate that that the element is not in the same namespace as its parent.

Comment: Thank you mister Michael Kay, your answer helped me to solve the problem. And now my Request is correct and web service return good response.